# How to resolve CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ A workflow or approval field update caused an error when saving this record. Order Name: data value too large:

Tags: apex, trigger, exception

I have a trigger code and I am trying to insert large data on `Order` `Name`. I get the below error:

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 8014B000000HkuPQAS;
>   first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, OSM_OrderTrigger:
>   execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update
>   failed. First exception on row 0 with id 8024B000000JxXQQA0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, A workflow or approval
>   field update caused an error when saving this record. Contact your
>   administrator to resolve it. Order Name: data value too large: Order 
>   (max length=80):

How to do I resolve this issue?

Comment: The error is right there in front of you. It says Order name is more than 80 characters

Comment: Can we avoid this error by code ?how can we handle this exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put split the name and then put the name in field. You can try the following piece of code in your trigger.

```
String str = 'kjsbjkcbjkadbscjkbjkabscbabcbsakbcjkbsabclkbaskjcbkcsvdgcjsvdcjhsdvchjsdhvchjsdvhjcsdjcbajcascascajnckjnjjkBCKJbkjckjnzkjckjdskjcbkbdskc';
str= str.substring(0,80);
System.debug(str);
campaign  camp=new campaign ();
camp.name=str;
insert camp;
```